# My script changes some values with what seems to be no reason

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on a script that spawns bubbles at the mouse coordinates. It is a very basic script that calculates some things like a random opacity, random size, etc.

```js
var transform = (function () { // This piece is to test whether transform should be prefixed or not
  var testEl = document.createElement('div')
  if (testEl.style.transform == null) {
    var vendors = ['Webkit', 'Moz', 'ms']
    for (var vendor in vendors) {
      if (testEl.style[ vendors[vendor] + 'Transform' ] !== undefined) {
        return vendors[vendor] + 'Transform'
      }
    }
  }
  return 'transform'
})()

var bubbles = {}
bubbles.chance = 0.08  // Chance for a bubble to spawn at mousemove
bubbles.delay = 50     // Should minimally be 10, otherwise the circles can't transition from small to big
bubbles.duration = 800
bubbles.minScale = 0.2 // The scale of the bubbles will be anywhere between 0.2 and 1 of the default size defined by the CSS
bubbles.minOpacity = 0.4
bubbles.maxOpacity = 0.7

document.getElementById('bubbles').addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  if (Math.random() < bubbles.chance) {
    var $el = document.createElement('div')
    var size = Math.random() * (1 - bubbles.minScale) + bubbles.minScale
    var transition = Math.round(bubbles.duration * 0.9)

    $el.style.transition = transition + 'ms ease-in-out'
    $el.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px'  // Seems to undergo a modulo for some periods of time
    $el.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px' // This one too
    $el.style[transform] = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)'
    $el.style.opacity = Math.random() * (bubbles.maxOpacity - bubbles.minOpacity) + bubbles.minOpacity

    window.setTimeout(function () {
      $el.style[transform] = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(' + size + ')'
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        $el.style[transform] = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)'
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          $el.parentNode.removeChild($el)
        }, transition)
      }, transition + bubbles.duration)
    }, bubbles.delay)

    document.getElementById('bubbles').appendChild($el)
  }
})
```

```css
html, body{height:100%}body{margin:0;background-color:#17C}

#bubbles{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bubbles > div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="bubbles"></div>
```

Now, for some reason, some of the bubbles aren't placed at the right coordinates. The script is supposed to literally take `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` every time it spawns a new bubble, but it sometimes seems to apply a modulo to the values.

The reason I think some kind of modulo is applied, is because when you only move in a horizontal line, all the displaced bubbles will also form a horizontal line. The same goes for vertical.

The script is vanilla JavaScript and the piece where the error seems to occur is here:

```
$el.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px'
$el.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px'
```

One weird thing to also note, is that the displacement isn't just occurring for one bubble at a time, but for all bubbles within short periods of time.

The bug occurs in all major browsers.

All input is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see why it's happening.  If you happen to hover over a bubble instead of the blue background, it uses the bubble as reference for offsetX and Y.  If it's a full page app, you could use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` instead.  Otherwise you need to listen only to the event if it's fired on `#bubbles`.

Comment: @Joseph Exactly what I was about to type after putting in CodePen

Answer (score 1):

it has nothing to do with modulo! the `offsetX` and `offsetY` is calculated from `e.target` which sometimes is the `bubbles` div BUT other times is the circle generated (since its nested inside) thats why you get a small offset from the mouse position to the circle, so the next circle gets little values.

in other words, the problem replicates whenever you mouse over the generated circles.

you can use `clientX` and `clientY` to get absolute values.

here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwhcoqzc/1/

additionally, you can use other methods, such as `prevent bubbling` with `useCapture`.